# Is it possible to show RadTab during Button Click event?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, telerik

```
protected void btnButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    rtImages.Visible = true;    
}
```

`BtnButton1` is a button, `rtImages` is a radtab.

Is it possible to make the rad tab visible in the button click event?  It doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the Visible property should do the job. If there are containers which host the tabstrip, can you check whether their visibility is set to true, too? Also in case you ajaxified the button, make sure that the tabstrip is specified as an updated control.